# Sketching a vector of a cyclist's route

Tags: vector-spaces

A cyclist travels at a steady $16 km/h$ on the four legs of his journey. From the origin O he first travels NE (north-east in the direction of the vector i + j) for one hour to the point A. He then travels due east for half an hour to point B, from where he travels NW to a point C which is due north of his starting point. He then travels due south to return to O.

At first I thought the sketch would be a parallelogram but he travels NW which is the upper left, this is where I got confused. Also, How do I find the vector AB? I used to deal with questions in the form i + j, not sure what to make of 16 km/h.

Comment: $ \ \vec{AB} \ $ is just due east, so it points in the direction $ \ \mathbf{i} \ $ ; $ \ \vec{BC} \ $ runs northwest, which is the direction $ \ -\mathbf{i} \ + \ \mathbf{j} \ $ ; $ \ \vec{CO} \ $ goes due south, which is $ \ -\mathbf{j} \ $ .  You are given the cyclist's speed, from which you figure out how long each vector "leg" is from the travel times, when that information is given.

Comment: Thanks. I tried drawing the sketch but I still can't. First, we draw a line due east, from there the line will go to northwest, and than due south which will cut our east line in the middle. I don't think I got it right. Is it supposed to form a shape like parallelogram?

Comment: The total round trip is _not_ a parallelogram. What is it you're supposed to answer about this vector problem, or is the problem to make a correct diagram with all of the lengths of the legs worked out?

Comment: There are several questions like getting the position vectors of A,B and C. Finding the equation of the line through B and C, and the distance from B to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear about what is being described in the problem, here is a graph of the vectors in the cyclist's path:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. One last thing, what is $\vec{AB}$ in this case? I know it is equal to $-(OA) + (OB)$ but what is the value of OA and OB?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but if you mean what the expressions for the vectors are, those would be $$ \vec{OA} \ = \ (16 \ \cos \ 45º)\mathbf{i} \ + \ (16 \ \sin \ 45º)\mathbf{j} \ \ , $$ $$ \vec{AB} \ = \ 8 \ \mathbf{i} \ \ , $$  $$ \vec{OB} \ = \ (16 \ \cos \ 45º \ + \ 8)\mathbf{i} \ + \ (16 \ \sin \ 45º)\mathbf{j} \ \ . $$